# how do i get the android emulator to report a specific screen size

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-screen, android-screen-support

I am trying to emulate the HTC Flyer and in order to do that I need the emulator to self-report as "large" screen size.  I have specified the resolution and the correct dpi but it reports as "xlarge".  The android documentation ( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range ) specifies that it should be "xlarge" but the HTC Flyer device says it's "large".  Here is some debug output with some numbers:

```
flyer device 

DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=600, height=1024, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=169.99738, ydpi=169.33333}, densityDpi, 160, density, 1.0, screen size, large,

flyer emulator

DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=600, height=1024, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=160.0, ydpi=160.0}, densityDpi, 160, density, 1.0, screen size, xlarge,
```

notice the "screen size".  Everything else is equal but the device reports "large" and the emulator "xlarge".  Is there a way to make the emulator report "large" instead?

Here is the java that gave me the output:

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int screenLayout = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    String screenLayoutStr;
    switch (screenLayout){
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            screenLayoutStr = "small";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            screenLayoutStr = "normal";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            screenLayoutStr = "large";
            break;
        case 4:
            screenLayoutStr = "xlarge";
            break;
        default:
            screenLayoutStr = "unknown: " + screenLayout;
    }
    LogIt.d(this,metrics,"densityDpi",metrics.densityDpi,"density",metrics.density,"screen size",screenLayoutStr);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the difference between the x/ydpi numbers make a difference? I am seeing 169.xx vs 160.0

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure how to set that and it doesn't seem like it's a factor in the size. Unless I am wrong.